# Postgresql: Subquery in FROM must have an alias - with multiple joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, orm

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 11:   (SELECT "domiciles"."id" AS id,
           ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
```

with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT "domiciles".*
FROM "domiciles"
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT "domiciles"."id" AS id,
          string_agg("locations"."name"::text, ' ') AS name
   FROM "domiciles"
   INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."id" = "domiciles"."place_id"
   AND "locations"."type" IN ('Place')
   GROUP BY "domiciles"."id") place ON place.id = "domiciles"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT "domiciles"."id" AS id,
          string_agg("accounts"."email"::text, ' ') AS email
   FROM "domiciles"
   INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "domiciles"."user_id"
   AND "accounts"."type" IN ('User')
   GROUP BY "domiciles"."id") user ON user.id = "domiciles"."id"
WHERE "domiciles"."deleted_at" IS NULL
```

**I have tried to add AS 'some_text' in many parts of the query, but I cannot solve this problem. Any idea?**

Here the complete SQL query to have an idea what I want to do:

```
SELECT "domiciles".*,
       ((ts_rank((to_tsvector('german', unaccent(coalesce("domiciles"."is_default"::text, ''))) || to_tsvector('german', unaccent(coalesce("domiciles"."created_at"::text, ''))) || to_tsvector('german', unaccent(coalesce("domiciles"."updated_at"::text, ''))) || to_tsvector('german', unaccent(coalesce(place.name::text, ''))) || to_tsvector('german', unaccent(coalesce(user.email::text, ''))) || to_tsvector('german', unaccent(coalesce(owner.email::text, '')))), (to_tsquery('german', ''' ' || unaccent('abc') || ' ''' || ':*')), 0))) AS pg_search_rank
FROM "domiciles"
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT "domiciles"."id" AS id,
          string_agg("locations"."name"::text, ' ') AS name
   FROM "domiciles"
   INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."id" = "domiciles"."place_id"
   AND "locations"."type" IN ('Place')
   AND "locations"."deleted_at" IS NULL
   GROUP BY "domiciles"."id") place ON place.id = "domiciles"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT "domiciles"."id" AS id,
          string_agg("accounts"."email"::text, ' ') AS email
   FROM "domiciles"
   INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "domiciles"."user_id"
   AND "accounts"."type" IN ('User')
   AND "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL
   GROUP BY "domiciles"."id") user ON user.id = "domiciles"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT "domiciles"."id" AS id,
          string_agg("accounts"."email"::text, ' ') AS email
   FROM "domiciles"
   INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."id" = "domiciles"."place_id"
   AND "locations"."type" IN ('Place')
   AND "locations"."deleted_at" IS NULL
   INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "locations"."user_id"
   AND "accounts"."type" IN ('User')
   AND "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL
   GROUP BY "domiciles"."id") owner ON owner.id = "domiciles"."id"
WHERE "domiciles"."deleted_at" IS NULL
  AND "domiciles"."user_id" = $1
  AND (((to_tsvector('german', unaccent(coalesce("domiciles"."is_default"::text, ''))) || to_tsvector('german', unaccent(coalesce("domiciles"."created_at"::text, ''))) || to_tsvector('german', unaccent(coalesce("domiciles"."updated_at"::text, ''))) || to_tsvector('german', unaccent(coalesce(place.name::text, ''))) || to_tsvector('german', unaccent(coalesce(user.email::text, ''))) || to_tsvector('german', unaccent(coalesce(owner.email::text, '')))) @@ (to_tsquery('german', ''' ' || unaccent('abc') || ' ''' || ':*'))))
```

Comment: `GROUP BY "domiciles"."id") user ON user.id = "domiciles"."id"` "user" is a reserved word. Don't use it (here) Just rename it to "uuu" or something (here)

Comment: Thx @wildplasser! Using `GROUP BY "domiciles"."id") "user" ON "user"."id" = "domiciles"."id"` solves the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! The following sentences:

```
place ON place.id
coalesce(place.name::text, '')
```

should be

```
"place" ON "place"."id"
coalesce("place"."name"::text, '')
```

and this for all sentences: **place, owner, user, id**

Comment: Why do you think you need double quotes? Lower case is the default for objects in PostgreSQL, no quoting needed.

Comment: Whitout I get errors, with quotes all works fine. Additionally some word are reserved and cannot be used. With quotes I can use it. Please read comment of @wildplasser in the question.